# Difference between where and which

Tags: unix, tcsh

What is the difference between the `where` and `which` command in Unix?

Comment: They both do pretty much the same job (finding executables in the path) but that job really doesn't have anything to do with programming per se :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean whereis? Which just finds the binary, whilst wehereis tries to find the source and manual pages too.

Answer (score 1):

"where" does not seem to be a common unix command and I could not find any man page for it.

However, ["where" does exist in most Windows OSs.](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html)

Looking at the aforementioned link.

```
WHERE (Windows 2003 + )

Locate and display files in a directory tree. 

The WHERE command is roughly equivalent to the UNIX 'which' command. 
By default, the search is done in the current directory and in the PATH.
```

which makes sense since the man page for "which" states:

```
WHICH(1)

NAME
   which - shows the full path of (shell) commands.
```

Are you using Cygwin?

I ask because this would be the most common case where both "which" and "where" would exist in the same environment.

In that environment, "which" would show where the command is in is path in a unix-like way.

```
$ which where
/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/where
```

and "where" would show the path in a windows like manner.

```
$ where which
C:\cygwin\bin\which.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: This is on a windows box using cygwin.

`Which` shows the full path of a one executable `Where` can show for multiple.

```
$which git sh
```

would produce something like `/bin/git/` relative path of the first arg passed but ,

```
$where git sh
```

produces the absolute path for all the arguments passed i.e
note I'm on a windows box so i get something to the effect of

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe
```

To add to the other answers I think where only exists in windows.